# Paging position is not fixed (Yii2)

Tags: html, css, yii2

I'm trying to display the list view with pagesize = 3. But somehow the pagination position is a little not parrallel on the other pages. Below are the pictures:

It supposed to be like this:

[image]

The last page become like this because it only have one album instead of 3:

[image]

Below are my coding:

**View(index.php):**

```
<div class="gallery-index">
<?php 
        //modal
        Modal::begin([
            'header' => '<h4>Setting</h4>',
            //'footer' => Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']). ' ',
            'toggleButton' => [
                'label' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>',
                'class' => 'btn btn-default'
            ],
        ]);

        echo $this->render('_formSetting', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);


        Modal::end();


        //listview        
    echo \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
        'id' => 'gallery-listview',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        //'layout' => "{items}\n{pager}\n{summary}",
        'layout'=>'{items}{pager}',
        'itemView' => function ($model) {
            return $this->render('_galleryItem',['model' => $model]);
        },
        'pager' => [
            'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
            'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
            'nextPageLabel' => '>>',
            'prevPageLabel' => '<<',
        ],

    ]);

    ?>

    <div>
```

**View(_galleryItem.php)**

```
<div class="col-sm-4 gallery-item">
<div class="image">
  <div class="case-study-gallery">
    <h1 class="title"><?= $model->name ?></h1>
    <p style="text-align:justify" ><?= $model->descr ?></p><br>
  <div class="case-study study1">
    <figure>
      <!--<img class="case-study__img" src="https://static.squarespace.com/static/51b79838e4b0b8b55c75cf91/t/51c4b688e4b03003ea9f1a63/1371846281755/Hexxis+Logo+White.png" alt="" />-->
    </figure>
    <div class="case-study__overlay">
      <h2 class="case-study__title"><?= $model->name; ?></h2>
      <!--<a class="case-study__link" href="#">View photos</a>-->
      <?= Html::a('View photos', ['view', 'id' => $model->gallery_id], ['class' => 'case-study__link']) ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you dont specify the `layout`, it should show you the pagination in the footer by default

Comment: ive tried but it is still the same.

Comment: then it must be related to your css classes that you are using , do you have any live link to the app

Comment: Yeah i think so. I use adminlte template and adding some styles into certain pages. I dont make it live yet huhu =="

Answer (score 1):

Apply this CSS and make it centre.

```
.pagination {
     margin: 20px auto 50px;
     text-align: center;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: still the same.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the margin for the pagination, ass auto. so that you wil be able to see the position same in all pages.refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_pagination.asp if you are using bootstrap https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_pagination.asp